# Reflexive pronouns to affect false intellectual tone

Tags: etymology, word-usage, tone

In the comments [on this answer from another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/336158/183702), a discussion was started regarding the way native speakers use reflexive pronouns to sound "more intellectual" (for example: "I myself have found in this research...").

I know it isn't *correct* in standard English, but I wonder if it has a literary history. Where does this come from? Has it been around for long? (All of my preliminary research has shown mostly anecdotal results, and I'm looking for actual data if it's available.)

---

An alternate hypothesis posited that really it's the *repetition* ("I myself", "you yourself", etc.) that is desired to give the appearance of intellectualism, and the (improper) use of reflexive pronouns may merely be a means to achieve that goal. Is the use of repetition shown more frequently in "intellectual" speech than just through improper reflexive pronouns?

---

(As an aside, I'd love to see anecdotes in the comments about whether this varies dramatically by region or other demographic grouping. I'm in the US, so my experiences are narrow.)

Comment: I work in corporate retail, and there are a lot of people who end emails with "if you have any further questions, please call [or email] myself." Drives me nuts!

Comment: There's nothing incorrect about this emphatic use; it's been around for at least 1100 years, and in fact seems to antedate the reflexive use by three hundred years or so. You may be thinking of object uses, like that instanced by Justin, which are different matter.

Comment: Interesting - I haven't come across this as a way to sound more intellectual as much as I've seen the imaginary-friends-who-agree-with-me 'We' that some folks use to try to give their opinions more credibility. I don't think it would flag as 'incorrect' to me, but I myself have used it on occasions where I want to emphasize that it was I in fact that did it, so I may be biased ;)

Comment: wouldn't it just be being used to add emphasis to e.g. contrast. as with themselves "used to emphasize a particular group of people or things mentioned"

Comment: @Pierce Darragh - Feel free to edit you question to look for answers that address examples like the one I gave in my comment.

Comment: I myself use this construction for emphasis (not to create the illusion that I'm smart).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it correct to say “I myself”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124786/is-it-correct-to-say-i-myself)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think not, as I was originally asking about its use in a specific setting. I think that other question would be a good supplemental reference, but I was not originally asking about the correctness of that use.

Comment: Your question is predicated on an error; the linked question exposes this error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a false premise (that the cited usage "isn't correct in standard English").

Comment: @FumbleFingers yeah, that's fair. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Pierce: I don't actually understand why you disagree that this is a dulicate of @Edwin's link, but to a certain extent I can see merit in the argument that if *you* don't think it is, we're probably not helping you if *we* closevote by citing that (it's a bit like forcing you to eat something you don't like, just because *we* like it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers while the answers may have ended up more or less the same, the intent of the question is different. Seems to me that while my question is predicated on a false premise, it's not really a "duplicate" of the other question linked.

Comment: Pierce: It's apparent from your comment to [a woefully inadequate answer posted a few hours ago](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336156/which-is-correct-you-and-mr-diddy-or-mr-diddy-and-yourself/336158#comment770903_336158) that you find some reflexive constructions *pretentious* (rather than simply *emphatic*). As with foods, I can't tell you what you do or don't like (that's just matter of how you yourself react! :) But whether or not your question gets closed, I think you have a perfectly reasonable answer from @David here. It's much better than the one you commented on earlier.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ah, I dunno about *pretentious*... I don't associate it with the metaphorical snooty yacht-going crowd, for example. It seems to me to happen more frequently when people are trying to sound *more professional*. Like in a corporate letter or something. But! You raise a valid point. Thanks for all the comments! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting a sentence with the words "I myself have found"
is *not* grammatically incorrect.

From [The Cambridge Dictionary:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-reflexive-myself-themselves-etc)

> Reflexive pronouns for emphasis
>
> We can use reflexive pronouns for emphasis:
>
> *The director of the company wrote to us **himself** to apologise for the dreadful service.* (or *The director of the company **himself** wrote to us to apologise for the dreadful service.*)
>
> We don’t use reflexive pronouns on their own as the subject of a clause, but we can use them with a noun or pronoun to emphasise the subject:
>
> *Parents and teachers always pass on to children what **they themselves** have been told, and this has been going on for hundreds, or even thousands of years.*

(This is about halfway down the page.)

While the use of a reflexive pronoun as an intensifier may be grammatically
correct, however, excessive use of intensifiers leads to bad writing.
In particular, pretentious speakers might put an unnecessary emphasis on
their own role in whatever they are describing as a way to make
themselves sound more important.

Comment: This is interesting to me, as I had always been taught that (from a prescriptivist perspective) it was grammatically incorrect to use this construction. So does "I myself" become a complex noun phrase then?

Comment: Additionally: it is still wrong to say, for example, "Turn the form in to myself" or "Myself went walking yesterday", right? Even though you could say (I suppose) "Turn the form in to me myself" or "I myself went walking yesterday"?

Comment: The first two are still wrong (unless the subject of "turn the form in" is also "I", for example in a "to do" list). The other two seem _technically_ grammatically correct, but could still be bad style; I have failed to think of any situation that justifies the intensification in "Turn the form in to me myself", and whether the last example is really OK would depend on context.